# stop start video recording bar similar to TikTok in react native

Tags: react-native, tiktoktemplate

hy, i want to implement that play and pause video recording bar at the top in a camera component  similar to that in tiktok in react native , I can't find any dependency and don't know how to do it ,please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-native-progress` to display a progress bar

Then use state to keep track of the progress:

```
const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0)
```

Then render the progress bar:

```
import * as Progress from 'react-native-progress';

<Progress.Bar progress={this.state.progress} width={200} />
```

now you can use `setInterval` to update the progress

```
setInterval(() => setProgress((prev) => return prev + (10/100))), 100)
```

This function increases the progress by 1% every 100 millisecconds you can change this to make the progress smoother